# GetObject within VB6 not working when UAC is turned to Default

Tags: vb6, uac

I'm trying to hook up to an already existing Word window.

Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If UAC is turned off this works fine.  If UAC is turned to "Default", I get an error. "ActiveX component can't create object".

Once thing I noticed in my experimenting is that if Word was started with "Run as Administrator", things work normally.  Unfortunately the box/login I'm expected to run on likely won't have admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue developers were educated on back in 2006.

You want both processes to have the same integrity level.  It sounds as if you are testing within the IDE running elevated, which should normally be the case.  When that is true then the process you want to automate must also be elevated.

This shouldn't be an issue when running normally, since both processes would typically by run at the same level, standard user.  If you need something other than this then you need a manifest with `uiAccess = True` and your code must be signed and formally installed.

See *User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI) and integrity* within [Windows Integrity Mechanism Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx).

But [automating Office has been deprecated for a very long time](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757).

Comment: I'm looking through the documentation now.  According to the process explorer tool, I can clearly see that my app is running with "integrity" equal to high and when I start an instance of word (manually) to hook up to, it has an integrity of Medium.  The problem still exists even outside the IDE, presumably because the integrity levels aren't the same?